# Derivative of real-time measurements

Tags: functions, derivatives

I am trying to understand what a derivative is in practice. I know that is the $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ and how that works when you have a function $f(x)$. But do derivatives work only with functions?

I am trying to make a program that receives some data using a DAQ and then a formula is applied. More specifically, I am reading the angular velocity (rad/s) of a wheel. I want to apply a formula that needs the derivative of the angular velocity, how do I do this? I don't have a specific function to just calculate its derivative. How do I apply the derivative definition at measurements that are received in real time?

The formula I need to use is
$$a = \frac{\mathrm d\omega}{\mathrm dt}$$
where $\omega$ is the angular velocity.

Comment: You have to approximate it, unfortunately such approximations tend to be noisy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute an average rate of change of angular velocity; say two measurements of angular velocity at times $a$ and $b$ are $\omega(a)$ and $\omega(b)$. Then the average rate of change of the velocity over that time interval is $$\frac{d\omega}{dt}\approx \frac{\omega(b)-\omega(a)}{b-a}.$$ This is an approximation to the derivative of the angular velocity. The derivative is exactly what you get from the formula above when you consider what happens when  $a$ and $b$ get arbitrarily close together. Accordingly, the formula above delivers better estimates of $\frac{d\omega}{dt}$ when $a-b$ is small.

This is analogous to calculating the average velocity of a car between times $a$ and $b$ by dividing the distance traveled ($d(b)-d(a)$) by the time elapsed ($b-a$).  You probably have some intuition for this already: it works well for intervals over which the car's velocity is not changing too much, including very short intervals. If you use this method to estimate the car's velocity where $a$ and $b$ differ by 1 second, you will get a good estimate, unless the car drove into a wall during that second; if you use it when $a$ and $b$ differ by three weeks, your estimate will probably not have much to do with what the car actually did during those three weeks, unless it was parked in the garage the whole time.

If the car's velocity does not change too rapidly, the average velocity calculated by the formula above will not be too different from the car's actual velocity at each instant.  (In fact there is a theorem, the “mean value theorem”, that says that there is at least one instant at which the car's actual  velocity was equal to the average velocity.)  Similarly if $\frac{d\omega}{dt}$ is not too large the estimate you get from the formula above will not be too bad.

Answer (score 0):

You want to calculate a derivative, but you don't have a function to differentiate. The gap between the numbers and the function is the *model*.

Let's try a simple model; suppose the value you measure is the exact value of the angular velocity ω(t), and you have perfect timestamps t, and the angular acceleration is constant.

Then

$$a = \text{const,} \\
\omega = \int a \; \text{d}t=at+c$$

So now we have an equation, and we can consider the measurements at $t_1$ and $t_2$:

$$\omega_1 = at_1 + c\quad\text{and}\quad\omega_2 = at_2 + c\\
\omega_1 - at_1 = \omega_2 - at_2\\
\omega_2 - \omega_1 = a(t_2 - t_1)\\
a=\frac{\omega_2 - \omega_1}{t_2 - t_1}$$

As you may imagine, the caveats about perfect measurement, perfect timing and constant acceleration are all wrong to some degree, so this is where the skill is in constructing a model; you could instead have the acceleration $a$ as a polynomial in $t$ with some error term - you could then see that with a set of $n$ samples you would be able to calculate the acceleration with some error term via a particular set of weights.

Alternatively, we can apply the neural network approach, and set up some code to guess a set of weights. This is fairly easy in Excel; given a polynomial of order 3, and a monte carlo set of 20 samples each with an error (normally distributed?) in both timing and value, perform an optimisation on the set of weights such that you minimise the error.

The model you use enters every assumption here, about how you interpret the values you measure, how you simulate calculating the result from the measurements, how you infer the error, what confidence you have in the final result.